# Export to Excel - Need Space in Between Text

Tags: jquery, html, export-to-excel

I have a HTML table and a button to export into Excel.  The exporting works well - every data from the table is brought into Excel, but in Excel, there is no space in between text when I use Chrome or Firefox to view the page and export!

Here is HTML code

```
<table>
<tr><td>Job Description</td></tr>
<tr><td><xsl:value-of select="job_desc" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

Here how it looks in the browser

```
Job Description
The process of writing a job description requires having a clear...
```

And here how it looks in Excel after exporting

```
JobDescription
Theprocessofwritingajobdescriptionrequireshavingaclear...
```

Then, I try to get a space in my hard code: `Job&#160;Description`. It works and let me have a space: `Job Description`

The issue is: How to get a space for a dynamic data?

Is that related to Jquery syntax I use to export data to Excel?

JS to export

```
$(".exportExcel").click(function(e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    var table = $("." + $(this).data('target'));
                    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $(table).html());
                    e.preventDefault();
                    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just changed

```
$(".exportExcel").click(function(e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    var table = $("." + $(this).data('target'));
                    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $(table).html());
                    e.preventDefault();
                    });
```

to

```
$(".exportExcel").click(function(e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    var table = $("." + $(this).data('target'));
                    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' +  encodeURIComponent(table[0].outerHTML));
                    e.preventDefault();
                    });
```

And I get spaces in between words.

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping your table with the **pre**    tag - preserves formatting:

```html
<pre>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Job Description</td></tr>
        <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="job_desc" /></td></tr>
     </table>
 </pre>
```

Comment: thank you very much!  I just tried and it doesn't work.