# Insert space into html tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, excel

I am using `window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,'  html)` to export an HTML table to Excel. I pass the HTML as a string and it works fine.

But I found problem when trying to add a `style` attribute. I had to change, for example, `<th>` to `<th style="background-color:cornflowerblue">` but the space between th and style disappears and I get `<thstyle="background-color:cornflowerblue">`. If it was a space in innerHTML, `&nbsp;` would be fine, but in this case I can't use `&nbsp;`.

Comment: My _hunch_ is that Excel doesn't know/care about CSS and/or HTML attributes... But I'm not super familiar with importing HTML tables into Excel so that's just a hunch.

Comment: If I correct it and add a space with a text editor, I got the wanted display.

Comment: Hmmm... interesting.  How are you adding the style at the moment?  Programmatically with JS?

Comment: your problem is very similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610932/export-to-excel-need-space-in-between-text)

Comment: @anied I am using a variable that contains html mixed with css to be the content of the created xls file. But when executing window.open spaces and breakline from sent content disappear. If i open with note pad the xls all the content is in one line without space: th and style become concatinated thstyle, and that is the problem. A quick manuel fix can help but client will not like it

Answer (score 0):

The way you are describing is not really the right way to do it.

You would need to set an attribute **style** with its value by using JavaScript

Since there isn't much you supplied in order to base my answer on that, you'd have to use the following DOM element: **setAttribute()**

Here's how it's done:

```
document.getElementById("yourID").setAttribute("style", "color: yourColor;");
```

Keep in mind that the above selector is selecting elements by their ID. You can also do that by TagName and instance just like here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp